# Changing variantions inside cart on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Hello I have a shop that needs to have variation selection inside a cart. When a user tries to change item variation page should refresh and update current item.
The problem is I cannot find a function that does that. I was thinking to use

`WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id,$quantity)` but this one does not fit my needs. Also I tried to change variation key inside. 

`WC()->cart` but that did not work either. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've found it myself
If you want to add variation just enter it inside third field like 
`WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id,$quantity,$variation_id)`